# SQL avg then trailing numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the average number, and then remove the trailing, pointless zeros afterwards, (new to SQL) but I can't understand why it wont remove them, do I have the wrong idea??

So far I have;

```
 SELECT total,
 AVG(total(TRUNCATE(total/1,2))
```

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired result.

Comment: So the number I am receiving is 17.80000, all I'm wanting is 17.8.

Comment: After avg? or before?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This is after the average is calculated, I am find with doing it before it's just afterwards I can't seem to get working

Comment: @jarlh PHPmyadmin

Comment: Then shouldn't you put the `TRUNCATE()` outside of the `AVG()`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA but then I would have a column for avg and then a seperate for the truncated. Which I do not want

Comment: `TRUNCATE(AVG(TRUNCATE(total,2)),2)`  this will trim the digits after 2 decimal both on individual values and on the computed average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `cast` as below.

```
select cast(17.800000 as dec(3,1))
```

**Result:**

```
val
----
17.8
```

so you query will be

```
SELECT total, cast(AVG(total) as dec(3,1))
```

considering you just need 2 digit before `.` If you need more digits, you can adjust it accordingly.

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/LQGT65921)**

Comment: This is not just done for one number though, there are all different totals that are in the column 17... was just an exampel

Comment: @bhigg890: It will be applied to all rows for column `total`. By providing the limited info, we can just guess what you are looking for...

Comment: Oh wait sorry I've read this wrong, yes this is what I am looking for thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure which DBMS you're using or what the implementation is, but a cast / truncation might end up with floating point arithmetic errors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server then you can cast the answer to a decimal with one decimal point:

select cast(avg(total) as decimal(9,1))

Answer (score 0):

This SQLFiddle shows it: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78329/1)

```
SELECT 
 TRUNCATE(AVG(myFloat), 2), 
 AVG(myFloat), 
 ROUND(AVG(myFloat), 2)
 FROM docs
```

You should probably use `ROUND` instead of `TRUNCATE`.

The stuff after the decimal is odd because of floating point math, and there are occasions where floating point math is internally calculated as `.009999999` instead of `.01000000000`

I believe these answers that use a `CAST` may have the same truncation problem.
You simply want to avoid casting or truncation when you are removing the decimal places beyond what you're interested in.  Be explicit in what you are doing and less mistakes will pop up later.